# Multi level lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

Playing around with parallel processing, I have a `Parallel.For` loop that does a lookup on an enumerable, and if it doesn't find what it's looking for, adds it. I keep running into issues where one thread modifies the enumerable while another thread is doing a lookup, though, which makes it throw an exception. The obvious solution is to use `lock` on both the lookup and the entry, but that's a bit brute force. I'd like it to be able to run multiple concurrent lookups, so I don't want to completely lock it while one thread is doing a lookup, but I do want to bar it from doing an add while a lookup is in progress. Is there any way of doing a two-level lock like that?

Comment: Consider using one of the thread safe collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent` instead.

Comment: What is the relation of # of writes to # of reads ? Are they coarsely the same? Far more Reads than Writes? Far more Writes than Reads? Efficient solutions may depend on that.

Comment: More reads than writes, but coarsely the same. I'm using the SharePoint.Client library, iterating through a number of folder names, checking whether each folder exists as a subfolder in SharePoint, and creating it if it doesn't.

Comment: If you make sure that each lookup is a O(1) operation, locking should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use a [ReaderWriterLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public string Read () {
    lock.EnterReadLock ();
    try {
        return "xxx";
    } finally {
        lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

public void Write () {
    lock.EnterWriteLock ();
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        lock.ExiteWriteLock ();
    }
}
```

Multiple threads may own the "reader" part of a ReaderWriterLock, but only one can own the "writer" part (and there can be no reader while there is a writer).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was after! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be thinking of using some form of immutable collection and `Interlocked` to replace the shared instance.

E.g. you mention "Look ups" so might an [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) be a good match?

Then for the lookup and update, you have something like:

```
var local = sharedReference;
while(!local.ContainsKey(lookupValue))
{
    var newValue = /* Whatever */
    var newLocal = local.Add(lookupValue,newValue);
    var result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sharedReference, newLocal, local);
    if(result == local) break;
    local = result;
}
//At this point, local definitely contains a key for lookupValue
```